# exposing a Java Map<> in Jython so that its keys are available with Python "dot" operator (attribute access)

Tags: java, python, jython

We have some `Map<String, Object>` in Java that I would like to make available into a Jython function. I would like to access the contents via

```
mymap.foo.bar
```

rather than

```
mymap['foo']['bar']
```

Is there a way to wrap the `Map` in an object so that it has this behavior in Jython? (e.g. like the `__getattr__` method in Python, only implemented in Java)

Comment: The ActiveState [`AttrDict`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict/) recipe may help. To make `mymap.foo.bar` work you'd need to have two levels of them.

Comment: For the record, Python's built-in `dict` requires the same sort of bracket notation access.

Comment: @MattBall yes, but it's easy to augment with a `__getattr__()` method. (especially if you're dealing with dicts with known keys.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing this:

```
@Override public PyObject __findattr_ex__(String name) {
    if (this.containsKey(name))
    {
        return Py.java2py(this.get(name));
    }
    else
    {
        throw Py.AttributeError(name);
    }
}
```

for an object that extends both `Map<String, Object>` and `PyObject`.