# implementing PyObject's dict lookup methods in Jython: (__finditem__ + ???)

Tags: java, jython

I have a Java class extending `PyObject` that contains a `Map<String,Object>` that I want to use for lookup, and I thought that I would have got the `dict` behavior for free in Jython. Instead I get an error `TypeError:` *myclassname* `object is unsubscriptable`.

It looks like I have to implement at least the [`PyObject.__finditem__()`](https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/tip/src/org/python/core/PyObject.java) method (see lines 654-670):

```
/**
 * Very similar to the standard Python __getitem__ method.
 * Instead of throwing a KeyError if the item isn't found,
 * this just returns null.
 *
 * Classes that wish to implement __getitem__ should
 * override this method instead (with the appropriate
 * semantics.
 *
 * @param key the key to lookup in this container
 *
 * @return the value corresponding to key or null if key is not found
 **/
public PyObject __finditem__(PyObject key) {
    throw Py.TypeError(String.format("'%.200s' object is unsubscriptable",
                                     getType().fastGetName()));
}
```

How should I do this? Is there an example of checking a `PyObject` if it's a `String`? What happens if the key is not a string?

Do I also have to override `__contains__`?

(This is similar to [exposing a Java Map<> in Jython so that its keys are available with Python "dot" operator (attribute access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468876/exposing-a-java-map-in-jython-so-that-its-keys-are-available-with-python-dot/33554612#33554612) but that had a relatively easy solution.)